# Translating this predicate logic statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Given that $P(x, y): “x + 2y = xy”$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers. How do we translate

$\lnot$$\forall$$x$ $\exists$$y$ $\lnot$$P(x,y)$

and what's the truth value of this?

Comment: You can convert "$\neg \forall x \exists y \neg P(x,y)$" to the equivalent "$\exists x \forall y P(x,y)$". But supposing you have such an $x$, $P(x,1)$ would certainly be false.

Answer (score 1):

$¬∀ ∃ ¬(,)$

Use the negated quantifiers,

$∃ ∀ (,)$.

This statement is True when there exists x, for all y, P(x,y) holds.

Suppose that $x=x_0$ exists,

Require to Prove: for all y, $P(x_0,y)$ holds for all  $y \in Z$.

Given that (,):“+2=”, where  and  are integers.

Require to Prove:  $(_0,):“_0+2=_0”$ holds for all $y \in Z$.

Require to Prove:  $(_0,):“_0+2=_0”$ holds for all  $y \in Z$.

Require to Prove:  $(_0,):“\frac{_0}{x_0-2}=, (x_0≠2)”$ holds for all  $y \in Z$.

This is not true as there exists y = 1, $(_0,)$ doesn't hold as $x_0≠x_0 -2$.

Hence, the statement is False.